# Flutter WebViewPLus setting height - not working

Tags: flutter, webview, height

I have a `ListView.builder` which contains several WebViewPlus widgets (among other widgets).

I am loading a local different HTML code into each one of them.

Setting the height after loading the HTML is not working for me.

Here is the code:

```
SizedBox(
  height: _height,
  child: WebViewPlus(
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
      _controller = controller;
      controller.loadString(html);
    },
    onPageFinished: (url) {
      _controller?.getHeight().then((double height) {
        print("New Height: $height");
        setState(() {
          _height = height;
        });
      });
    },
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  ),
),
```

I used the simplest solution of Future getting the correct height.

The problem is, that the height of all WebViewPlus widgets is eventually set as the last WebViewPlus. It is not being dynamically to each one.

I also tried using a `List<double>` for the different heights and it didn't help.

Any one have an idea how to do this correctly?

BTW, I also tried using InAppWebView widget, but this cause iOS to crash, so I move back to WebViewPlus.

Thank you guys!